# Creating a "Copy button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, as I was searching on the internet for some basic codes to examine - I found this one. A simple code which is supposed to copy the selected text. As i am a complete newbie in JS, I check the meaning of the methods that I didn't understand - and rewrited the code, as i make a few adjustments.

And still the code is not working and If someone can explain - this part ""copyit(this.form.select1)"" - Even though I kind of understand "this" - i am not able to understand what is doind here

```
function copyit(theField) {
var selectedText = document.getSelection();
if (selectedText.type == 'Text') {
  var newRange = selectedText.createRange();
  theField.focus();
  theField.value = newRange.text;
} else {
  alert('select a text in the page and then press this button');
}
}
</script>



<form name="it">
<div align="center">
<input onclick="copyit(this.form.select1)" type="button" value="Press to copy the highlighted text" name="btnCopy">
<p>
<textarea name="select1" rows="4" cols="45"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the original code - and it is not working either

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function copyit(theField) {
var selectedText = document.selection;
if (selectedText.type == 'Text') {
  var newRange = selectedText.createRange();
  theField.focus();
  theField.value = newRange.text;
} else {
  alert('select a text in the page and then press this button');
}
}
</script>


And in the body of your web page, add the following where you want the text to appear:
<form name="it">
<div align="center">
<input onclick="copyit(this.form.select1)" type="button" value="Press to copy the highlighted text" name="btnCopy">
<p>
<textarea name="select1" rows="4" cols="45"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="copyit(this.form.select1)"
```

executes the `copyit()` function and passes a variable which is later named `theField`. The variable that is passed is `this.form.select1` which is a textarea with ID `select1` which is located in the same form as the input you're clicking hence the `this.form`.

As to why your code isn't working - you should include here the original code before your adjustments. You probably deleted/changed something you shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking to, when someone clicks on any button/div, it copies a text you want for his clipboard? If no, ignore my comment, if yes, i'll explain:

First place, where should an user click?

```
<a class="btn" CopydivFunction(#text)">CLICK ME TO Hello.</a>
```

Now, add the function with JS.

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Now, place the text you want somebody to copy (hide it):

```
<h1 id="text" class="hidden">some text. This part won't be seen because of the hidden class, and this is the text that will be copied to your clipboard.</h1>
```

Place display:none on css:

```
#text{
display:none;
}
```

I think you have to add that, so nobody sees it.
And that should be it, click the `<a>` and you get the text in the `h1#text`